# The @login_required decorator of Django redirects people to /accounts/login when they aren't registered. How to change this URL?

Tags: python, django, configuration, authentication

I want it to redirect to "/login" instead of "/accounts/login"

Is there a setting I can change?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `LOGIN_URL = '/login'` to your settings.py

See [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#login-url) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

@login_required(login_url='/login/')

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/

Answer (score 0):

**LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login'** will solve your problem. 
LOGIN_URL = '/login' is just for telling django that '/login' is your login URL and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL will tell django where to redirect user after login.